# get string from arraylist and settext inside fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist

I want to get string from arraylist inside oncreateview fragment but i cant figure itout since no position index has been pass. get(position) return error.
String price = arrayList.get(position).getPrice();

i need to get string price and settext for price.this is my main concern.
this values should return from arraylist.

this is response JSON array from volley using mysingleton.

```
Single Product Response: [{"price":"75","date":"2017-07-13 03:25:31","pk_i_id":"4"}]
```

this main activty fragment

```
    public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView product,price,date,title;
    private String product_id;

    ArrayList<ProductItem> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity, container, false);

        product = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);


        if (getArguments() != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "getArgument is not null");
            product_id = getArguments().getString("product_id");
            ProductBackgroundTask productBackgroundTask = new ProductBackgroundTask(this.getActivity(), product_id);
            arrayList = productBackgroundTask.getList();

            String price = arrayList.get(position).getPrice();
//            Log.d(TAG, "price: " + price);

            product.setText(product_id);
//            price.setText(price);

        }else {
            Log.i(TAG, "getArgument is null");
        }


        return view;
    }

}
```

this is task to get arraylist using volley

```
    public class ProductBackgroundTask {
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<ProductItem> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String json_url = "phpfile.php";
    private String product_id;

    public ProductBackgroundTask(Context context, String product_id) {
        this.context = context;
        this.product_id = product_id;
    }

    public ArrayList<ProductItem> getList(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, json_url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Single Product Response: " + response);
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);
                                ProductItem productItem = new ProductItem(jsonobj.getString("price"), jsonobj.getString("date"), jsonobj.getInt("pk_i_id"));
                                arrayList.add(productItem);

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("product_id", product_id);
                return params;
            }
        };

        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

and this is class of array list

```
public class ProductItem {
private String Price,Date;
private int ProductId;


public ProductItem(String Price, String Date, int ProductId){
    this.setPrice(Price);
    this.setDate(Date);
    this.setProductId(ProductId);
}

public int getProductId() {
    return ProductId;
}

public void setProductId(int productId) {
    ProductId = productId;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return Price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    Price = price;
}

public String getDate() {
    return Date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    Date = date;
}
```

Comment: It will always returns null list because API take time to response. Use asytask or pass data in `onResponse()`.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly in your oncreate you haven’t initialized the product item and you cannot parse the complete list.You can try two to solve this

1.Pass specific item number instead of position i.e
say if you want to show 4th item then position=3

2.Or write a loop like this to parse entire arrayList like this

```
     for(ProductItem productItem:arrayList){
       String price = productItem.getPrice();

      // Log.d(TAG, "price: " + price);

        product.setText(product_id);
        price.setText(price);
       }
```

Comment: post error..I assumed you are getting data from the response..you are getting data right?

Comment: the data was parse into jSON onresponse then insert into ArrayList<ProductItem>. the problem only i want get string from this arraylist

Comment: but what is the position?Its an arraylist there wil be "n" positions

Answer (score 0):

Mistake you're doing is that in the MainActivityFragment your trying to assign the value to the arrayList even before the data is added to the arrayList in the ProductBackgroundTask-getList. That's the reason you are getting the list null all the time. Try to use interfaces.

1.Make your MainActivityFragment implement the interface.

2.Set the value to the interface method once you get the data from the server.

3.Get the data in the MainActivityFragment inside interface method and do all the operation you're doing inside the onCreateView method.

Now your arraylist will have the data whatever you received from the server.

Below is the link for the example on interfaces if you haven't used them before. He is doing exactly as your requirement.

https://www.justinmccandless.com/post/setting-up-a-callback-function-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Allow me. The `arrayList` that you return from `getList` isn't populated at the time you call `String price = arrayList.get(position).getPrice();`. The server call using volley takes some time to process and that's when the `onResponse` gets called. This happens AFTER you've returned the arrayList which is in fact empty.

The sequence of events is as follows.

• Call to `arrayList = productBackgroundTask.getList();` which returns an empty ArrayList.

• `String price = arrayList.get(position).getPrice();`

**Now after a while..**

• `onResponse` inside `getList()` gets called.

Do you now see why it's empty?

**Simple Solution**:
 • Define a simple interface `ProductListener` alongside `ProductBackgroundTask`. (With only a single abstract method `onProducts`).

• Instantiate it inside the Fragment's `onCreateView` using an anonymous class and pass it to the constructor of `ProductListener` to save it for later use. Do whatever you want to do with the products inside the `onProducts` method. (Since that will be called with the actual data)

• Call its `onProducts` method with the data that's parsed and fetched inside the `onResponse` method.

`ProductBackgroundTask` code:

```
      public class ProductBackgroundTask {
        private Context context;

        // I removed the instance ArrayList since that can be made 
        // local.
        // Here, we add a reference to our callback interface as we can use it later. 

        private ProductListener listener;

        String json_url = "http://192.168.43.55/android/v1/productList.php";
        private String product_id;

        // Instantiate this class using an additional listener argument 
        // which would be a concrete implementation of our interface.

        public ProductBackgroundTask(Context context, String product_id, ProductListener listener) {
            this.context = context;
            this.product_id = product_id;
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        // getList should not return anything,  
        // so I keep the return as void.

        public void getList() {
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, json_url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            ArrayList<ProductItem> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Single Product Response: " + response);
                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(response);
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);
                                    ProductItem productItem = new ProductItem(jsonobj.getString("price"), jsonobj.getString("date"), jsonobj.getInt("pk_i_id"));
                                    arrayList.add(productItem);

                                }

                                // Notice this line here, this is what 
                                // calls the callback with the products.
                                listener.onProducts(arrayList);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("product_id", product_id);
                    return params;
                }
            };


   MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

            }
        }

    // Callback interface, we would need a concrete implementation
    // of this and pass that to the constructor of ProductBackgroundTask.

    interface ProductListener {
       void onProducts(ArrayList<ProductItem> products);
    }
```

The code inside `onCreateView`:

```
    ProductBackgroundTask productBackgroundTask = new ProductBackgroundTask(this.getActivity(), product_id, new ProductListener() {

    // This method will be called with the needed products.
    // Give an anonymous class implementation of our interface
    // right here since we won't be using it anymore.

    public void onProducts(ArrayList<ProductItem> products) {
       // Get the price you want.
       String str = arrayList.get(0).getPrice();

       // Use str wherever necessary. Use the UI thread here if you need
       // to change any visible elements on the screen. 
    }
  });

  // Simply call this method to get the ball rolling.
  productBackgroundTask.getList();
```

This is a concrete implementation of the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46399005/7641174) answer and you won't be changing much code.

Comment: sorry little bit lost, there were error public interface ProductListener .if i follow this code,apps crash.

Comment: Did you use the UI thread for updating the UI or just printed out str in onProducts? Also, please post the error here so I can see if I've made a syntax error.

Comment: im little bit new this android devt,i just copy your code,the first show the interface should not be public and this from logcat 09-25 07:22:29.794 32579-32579/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-25 07:22:29.794 32579-32579/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2

Comment: remove public from the interface. Now, show the first line of the log that shows up in red in the Android Monitor as soon as the app crashes.

Comment: error void onProducts(ArrayList<ProductItem> products) should be public,change that still crash error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: Does your "Single Product Response" printing okay? Does that have data inside it? Did you check the response string coming from the server?

Comment: its ok for data.Single Product Response: [{"price":"75","date":"2017-07-13 03:25:31","pk_i_id":"4"}] . only difficult because the data was parsed into fragment oncreate view.

Comment: How many times do you see the Single Product Response for a single getItems call?

Comment: Also is your listener.onProducts written inside the try block as in case of the answer or after catch?